# Immediate Window and runtime giving different results for same LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a piece of code that simply compares two collections, and returns all items from one list which doesn't belong in the other.

As these two lists contain objects that aren't equitable by reference, I have a simple `IEquatable` which compares the objects on their IDs.

The code I am running is as follows:

```
private PreferenceDefinition[] FindUserPreferencesToAdd(PreferenceDefinition[] newDefinitions, PreferenceDefinition[] oldDefinitions)
{
     //Get the newly selected definitions
     var newPreferences = newDefinitions.Where(def => def.IsSelected);

     //Get all new definitions that don't exist in the old list
     var preferencesToAdd = newPreferences.Where(def => !oldDefinitions.Contains(def)).ToArray();

     return preferencesToAdd;
}
```

The result of `preferencesToAdd` gives me the exact same list in `newPreferences`, despite purposely ensuring that `newDefinitions` contains an additional item that has been selected. If I pass in 7 new preferences, it will return 7 preferences to 'add' - an incorrect implementation.

However, when I run the exact same LINQ statement in the Immediate Window when I hit a breakpoint on the return, it gives me:

```
newPreferences.Where(def => !oldDefinitions.Contains(def)).ToArray();
{App1Test.PreferenceDefinition[1]}
    [0]: {App1Test.PreferenceDefinition}
```

This contains the single result that should be added.

Why would the immediate window give me the correct result, but run time code wouldn't? I tried running this statement in the immediate window before and after the runtime LINQ query ran to ensure it wasn't an order of operations thing, but it made no difference.

Edit:

I have found a solution to my issue, by replacing the second LINQ statement with:

`var preferencesToAdd = newPreferences.Where(d => !oldDefinitions.Any(def => def.Equals(d))).ToArray();`

However I don't understand why the original did not work. I have a very similar scenario which does the opposite of what i'm trying to achieve here (find items to delete), and it works fine. Am I missing something?

Edit 2:

This code, even without IEquatable, worked fine:

```
private PreferenceDefinition[] FindUserPreferencesToDelete(PreferenceDefinition[] newDefinitions, PreferenceDefinition[] oldDefinitions)
{
    //Get the newly selected definitions
     var newPreferences = newDefinitions.Where(def => def.IsSelected);

     //Get all old definitions that don't exist in this new list
     var preferencesToDelete = oldDefinitions.Where(def => !newPreferences.Contains(def));

     return preferencesToDelete.ToArray();
}
```

Why would this work fine, but the first method wouldn't?

Comment: Show your IEquatabe implementation.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It's simply  `public bool Equals(PreferenceDefinition other)
        {
            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }`

Comment: @plusheen: Just an aside, but your `Equals` implementation should gracefully deal with the possibility of `other` being `null`.

Comment: @sstan ahh yes! how short sighted of me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base
>   class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that
>   their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable.Equals
>   method.

You can clearly deduct that the **==** operator is not affected by implementing **IEquatable**;

Therefore your **Equals** call uses your custom equality method and the **Contains** internally use the **Object.Equals** which is not overridden.

The array implements **ICollection** therefore the **Contains** method used internally is implemented in array with **IndexOf** without using the **EqualityComparer.Default** which tries to use the **IEquatable.Equals** if any.

Try adding this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var test = obj as Test;

    return test == null ? obj.Equals(this) : Equals(test);
}
```

You can see a simple example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C5R4bE

Comment: @sstan no, it does not. Test it for yourself and then remove the pointless downvote.

Comment: My mistake. I just noticed that the `Enumerable.Contains` implementation does take advantage of the `IEquatable<T>`, but only if the `IEnumerable<T>` is *not* an `ICollection<T>`. If it's an `ICollection<T>`, then it takes a different path which does behave as you described.

Comment: @sstan Exactly; but I do agree it's misleading.

Comment: May I suggest that you simplify your `Equals` method to simply: `public override bool Equals(object obj) => this.Equals(obj as Test);`. If the `IEquatable` interface is implemented correctly, that should be enough. The problem with your current code is that you will get an exception if `obj` is `null`, which is a valid use case.

Comment: Thanks @Uno , this makes my code work with the contains function. So as I understand it, my implementation of IEquatable was basically doing nothing? The strange thing is, I have similar code that is basically the opposite, and this works fine. I added it as an edit in my question, would you be able to take a look and see why it worked fine? Thanks

Comment: No problem; Basically, if you use `Contains` on a collection that does not implement `ICollection`, it's likely that it will work (depending on the implementation of the collection, of course). Have a look at the remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'll try to find an example later. Meanwhile, have a look at line 1249: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d1530e4eed8b26b3

Comment: @Uno Ah I see. The first expression that worked did a contains on `IEnumerable`, which doesn't implement `ICollection`, which used my `IEquatable` implementation. The second expression did a contains on an array, which implements `ICollection`, and as such used a different method for the comparer. Is that the gist of it? Cheers :)

Comment: @plusheen Correct :)